# Determining time-complexity for a function (Big O notation)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I had an algorithm test at my school and there was a code like this:

```
def a(A : list, i : int) -> int:

    if i == 0:
        return 1

    s = 0
    for j in range(i):
        if A[j] <= A[i]:
            s = max(s, a(A,j))
    return s + 1
```

I tried to calculate the big O notation of this code. However, I did not have any idea about the complexity when it ran in the recursion parts. Could anyone please help me with this problem?